# 2 Homescreens in one APK

Tags: android

For a demonstration app I'm working on a custom Android Homescreen.
The homescreen needs to have 2 variations, as it will be installed on different DEMO devices.
I don't want to create multiple APK installations, but simply reuse the same apk.

My AndroidManifest.xml defines 2 homescreen activities:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <activity android:name=".Homescreen_"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".map.HomescreenMap_"
              android:label="@string/app_name_map"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

So the problem is that when I press Home on the device and choose the other hoomescreen, it won't change the VIEW. However, in the log I can see the other homescreen Activity is indeed starting.

In the Android logs I can see the other Homescreen is starting:

```
10-08 12:09:40.014: INFO/ActivityManager(146): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity u=0} from pid 146
10-08 12:09:40.444: INFO/ActivityManager(146): Displayed android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity: +401ms
10-08 12:09:41.824: INFO/ActivityManager(146): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x13200000 cmp=com.company/.map.HomescreenMap_ u=0} from pid 146
```

But the UI will not be shown, neither will be any messages I put in the onStart method.

Once I open the Homescreen from the standard launchers App drawer, it works.
The activities don't inherit from each other, I tried that as well.